# Piano scale fingering difference between one and multiple octave target

Tags: piano, scales, practice, fingering

I'm a piano beginner and trying to practice scales correctly. What confuses me is that all guides mention how important it is to practice scales, but none are explaining the difference in fingering when one aims to practice only one octave, or multiple.

E.g. the D major scale for the left hand. Guide happily recommends to start with the 5th on D, the pinky finger. Yes great, that is easy until I want to go over more than one octave, because then I get confused - when I reach D again and I want to go on, the fingering doesn't fit.

I figured out that actually I have to start with my index finger on D, then thumb on E, fourth on F#, third on G, index on A, thumb on B, third on C# so I land again on D with my index finger.

I'm afraid if I learn the "easy" fingering for only one octave, I will teach my muscle memory incorrect stuff.

So my question is: Shouldn't I practice - even if I do only one octave - the (in my opinion correct) fingering for being prepared to go beyond an octave?

Comment: What are your piano goals? If you want to get a university degree in music, which country are you in?

Comment: Hey Todd, my goals are not to get a degree, I am just a hobbyist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fine practising the way you do for one octave.

Then for multiple octaves, you need to use thumb on the D, and 'move over' so that your ring finger is on the adjacent E, just like it was in the 1st octave. That can (and does) carry on for as many octaves as you wish. Always playing D with the thumb.

While there is actually 'recommended' fingering published by the various exam boards, in an exam, the candidate can use whatever fingering they like, as long as the audible end product is good - the actual fingering is never judged or marked. Just as playing pieces, we're all different in our physical size, stretch etc, so whatever suits  best is what should be used.

Comment: Many thanks, that helps. Is there a good free resource online you can recommend for scale fingering?

Comment: There's bound to be - just Google. But it's not what happens on this site.

Comment: In universities in the US, we are judged on scale fingerings. For D major, we must start finger 1 on right hand and finger 5 on left hand and cross with the third finger for the first crossing and then fourth finger at the end of the first octave to play the second octave. We must play two octaves up and down simultaneously on both hands to pass keyboard skills classes. We may also be required to play all scales with correct fingering for graduate school.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that's interesting. In UK, the examiner will most often not even sit where s/he can see the keys themselves. Seems incredibly harsh that fingering needs to be adjudicated too. Wonder what the reasoning is behind that. Are facial expressions given marks too..?  In my opinion there are lots of Stack questions where location would be a helpful addition, don't you think. Easy to add.

Comment: Facial expressions are only graded for voice, dance, and I think musical theatre, and of course acting. Although to be fair, I don't know what conservatory-style schools are like. Someone who wants to be a professional performer may want to spend some time on their facial expressions and while that might not be graded, it might be judged in some way for a performance degree.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - actually I was being flippant...

Comment: I knew that, but your flippant question had an answer that I thought might be edifying to future readers. I expect the reason we are judged on fingerings is because there are many fingerings where the player cannot develop as much speed or articulation. So while there may be more than one effective fingering for a given scale, there are many ineffective fingerings, and at the undergraduate level, there is only time to teach a single good fingering for each scale. Also there is a lot of overlap, so for most scales we use the same or essentially the same fingering.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - o.k. but on a serious note, I often seem to find that scale fingerings are restricted to just that - scale fingerings. When partial scales occur in pieces, those same fingerings don't help much, given the preceding or succeeding part that needs fingering, and the scale fingering leaves one on the wrong finger for one, the other, or both.

Comment: I've had the opposite experience. In fact, some of the fingerings we've been taught I've already known because I've used them to effectively play passages in pieces. Namely, when there's a significant scalar run in a piece, the fingering for the scale influences the fingering for the notes played before the scale starts so that one can start the scale on the right finger, or one starts the scale on the "wrong" finger but then uses an earlier than usual crossing to re-align the fingering. I've found that to be critical to play certain pieces at tempo.

Answer (score 2):

The use of finger 5 in scales is just a matter of convenience/convention when starting (left hand) or ending (right hand).

For both hands imagine a continuous, infinite scale. Each octave would start (left hand) or end (right hand) with the thumb rather than the pinkie. It's a bit awkward in practice to start or end a scale that way, but try it a few times, and it will be clear how to play multi-octave scales. You can then put finger 5 back in for the first or last note.

In terms of traditional fingerings, this only applies to major and minor for C, D, E, G, A, plus F (left hand) and B (right hand). All other scales avoid finger 5 entirely: C#/Db, D#/Eb, F#/Gb, G#/Ab, A#/Bb, plus F (right hand) and B (left hand).